# Redux store.getState() returning initial state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a Redux store configured and I'm trying to access the state from outside of a React component. I'm using `store.getState()` but it's returning the initial state values for everything in the store even though the store is populated with the correct data (visible in the UI and dev tools). It just seems to be that when the store is imported and the state is accessed via `getState()` that the initial values are returned instead of what is actually in the store. Code below.

**store.ts**

```
    import * as _ from "@reduxjs/toolkit/node_modules/redux-thunk";
    import { Action, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import { ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import reducers from "./reducers";

    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: reducers,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
            getDefaultMiddleware({
                serializableCheck: false,
            }),
    });

    export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

    export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

    export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, IRootState, unknown, Action<string>>;

    // Export a hook that can be reused to resolve types
    export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

    export default store;
```

**Service that I'm calling the store from:**

```
    import store from "store";
    import { LoggingService } from "logger";

    const logData(data) {
      const user = store.getState().user;
      
      LoggingService.log(user.email, data);
    }
```

In the example above, the `store.getState().user` returns an object, but the `email` is null. However, the `email` is actually populated as it can be seen in the UI and in dev tools. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also to note, this is not an SSR app.

Answer (score 0):

The `store.getState()` only returns current state from redux store once. Subsequent changes to the state via dispatch action will not call this method again unless use [subscribe(listener)](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener).

Instead of using `store.subscribe` directly, we can write a custom observable store utility. Why? see [issue#303](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/303)

`index.js`:

```
export function toObservable(store) {
  return {
    subscribe({ onNext }) {
      let dispose = store.subscribe(() => onNext(store.getState()));
      onNext(store.getState());
      return { dispose };
    },
  };
}
```

How to use it? Let's write a test to explain this:

```js
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { toObservable } from './';

const LoggingService = {
  log: console.log,
};

describe('toObservable', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    function userReducer(state = { email: '' }, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_USER_FULFILLED':
          return { ...state, ...action.payload };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
    const store = createStore(combineReducers({ user: userReducer }));

    // create store observable somewhere, may be in the application initialization phase 
    const store$ = toObservable(store);
    store$.subscribe({ onNext: (state) => LoggingService.log(state.user.email) });

    // Later, dispatch action in component
    store.dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER_FULFILLED', payload: { email: 'example@gmail.com' } });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS   redux-toolkit-example  packages/redux-toolkit-example/examples/observer-store/index.test.ts
  toObservable
    ✓ should pass (23 ms)

  console.log


      at onNext (packages/redux-toolkit-example/examples/observer-store/index.test.ts:22:58)

  console.log
    example@gmail.com

      at onNext (packages/redux-toolkit-example/examples/observer-store/index.test.ts:22:58)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.937 s
```

As you can see, every time the state changes, the `onNext` method will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I don't think it addresses the issue I'm having. I don't want to call my `LoggingService.log` every time the state changes. The logger is used separately elsewhere in the app and is not directly tied to any state changes. It simply needs to access the state only to grab some relevant information from it before it logs something (in this case, the user's email)

Answer (score -1):

store.getState() does not update immediately.
You have to use useSelector hook in Functional Component in order to get the updated state from the redux.
like:

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
```